# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' In SQLAlchemy python 3.8.2

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\flask_app\connecting_to_database\application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .sql import (
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .expression import (
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .visitors import Visitable
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .. import util
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce,  \
  File "C:\Users\Anirudh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 234, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: When submitting a question some background information is advisable. Please indicate OS and version, full Python version, SQLALchemy version, flask_sqlalchemy version. Also where is being run virtualenv, system, etc.  Just noticed that visitors.py is in sqlalchemy package. Is that your module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because in python 2, there is `time.clock()`, but in python 3, it has been replaced with `time.perf_counter()`.

Just replace all the `time.clock` to `time.perf_counter`, and it should be fine. For more info: https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/08/python-clocks-explained/

Comment: Except this is coming from the SQLAlchemy compat.py module. I'm not seeing ```time_func = time.clock``` here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py. I suspect there is a version mismatch in either the Python or SQLAlchemy being used.

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue with SQLAlchemy 1.2.10. Upgrading to the current version  (1.3.18 as of now) fixed the problem

```
pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that worked for me
I have a virtual environment carpet named env in which I installed sqlalchemy
So, env\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy_*init*_.py
Inside that there is this code:

```
   if sys.platform == 'win32':
        _timer = time.clock
   else:
        _timer = time.time
```

And I changed clock to perf_counter()
_timer = time.perf_counter()

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version solves the problem.

`pip install flask_sqlalchemy --upgrade`