# Chatterbot : AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

I am trying to create a chatbot, but since latest version of chatterbot was not getting installed on my pc so I installed chatterbot by using `pip install chatterbot==1.0.4` and the following error is showing up.

How do I resolve this?

Below is the code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

bot = ChatBot("My Bot")

convo = [
    'hello',
    'hi there',
    'what is your name?',
    'My name is BOT, I am created my a hooman ',
    'how are you',
    'i am doing great these days',
    'thank you',
    'in which city you live',
    'i live in kalyan',
    'in which languages do you speak',
    'i mostly talk in english'
    
]

trainer=ListTrainer(bot)

trainer.train(convo)

print("Talk to Bot")
while True:
    query=input()
    if query=='exit':
        break
    answer=bot.get_response
    print("bot : ", answer)
```

output :

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\GIT VS CODE\Py> & D:/Python/python.exe "e:/GIT VS CODE/Py/chatbot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\GIT VS CODE\Py\chatbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = ChatBot("My Bot")
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in __init__  
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 22, in __init__
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>     
    from . import util as _util  # noqa
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg  # noqa
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of python are you running? `time.clock` has been removed for py 3.8+

Solutions include downgrading python or altering the source it seems:

- [AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8)

  > From the Python 3.8 doc:

  > The function time.clock() has been removed, after having been deprecated since Python 3.3: use time.perf_counter() or time.process_time() instead, depending on your requirements, to have well-defined behavior. (Contributed by Matthias Bussonnier in bpo-36895.)
- [Solution for - AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609296/solution-for-attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock)

---

In Response to your comment: I'm assuming the chatterbox devs will fix this eventually but yes, downgrading to Python 3.7 will fix this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.clock

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.8: The behaviour of this function depends on the platform: use perf_counter() or process_time() instead, depending on your requirements, to have a well defined behaviour.

Comment: so if i install python 3.7 it will get resolved? i am using 3.9.2

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @Glycerine's answer, well, if you don't want to downgrade your python version, I have another solution for you.

Open the file <Python-folder>\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py
Go to line 264 which states:

```py
if win32 or jython:
    time_func = time.clock
    
else:
    time_func = time.time
```

Change it to:

```py
if win32 or jython:
    #time_func = time.clock
    pass
else:
    time_func = time.time
```

Simply here we are avoiding the use of `timer.clock` method and the `time_func` object because I saw that this object is just created for nothing and does nothing. It is just created and left untouched.

I don't know why even this exists when it is of no use. But this should work for you.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I tried this
`import time time.clock = time.time`

form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71415163/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-chatterbot), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert, but have you tried 'import time' in the top of your code. Worked for me when I was using time.sleep() in my pythoncode