# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' chatterbot

Tags: python, chatterbot

Just started with the chatterbox application and got this error:-
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQUTd.png)

After some research, I found that time.clock has been removed for py 3.8+. My python version is 3.9.7. I have checked the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8), but after checking the directory of my error code I am unable to find the code mentioned there:-

***Step 2***

Go to your error the last line and go to that directory and open that particular file.
search **time.clock** using ctrl+f and replace it with **time.time**

time.clock is not there.

How to proceed on this?

Comment: Your error traceback shows you the exact location of the source file (".../util/compat.py").  That's the file you need to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use this - to get your time

```
import time
time.clock = time.time
```